# Email not receiving with codeigniter on registration

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using a custom helper function to send email.

It works fine with forget email, but does not receive email on registration.
This is what I am trying.

```
function sendEmail($to, $subject, $user_data, $view) {
    $config = array('charset' => 'utf-8', 'wordwrap' => TRUE, 'mailtype' => 'html');

    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('email');
    $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $CI->email->from('noreply@example.com', 'Example');
    $CI->email->to($to);
    $CI->email->subject($subject);

    if ($view && $view != NULL) {
        $message = $CI->load->view('test', $user_data, true);
    } else {
            $message = $user_data[0];

    }
    $CI->email->message($message);
    $CI->email->send();
}
```

This works fine with forgot, but not working on registration.

```
// Register email
$user_data = array();
$user_data['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
$view = 'test';
$subject= 'Registered Successfully';
sendEmail($to, $subject, $user_data, $view);
$data->success = 'Account created successfully';

// Forgot email 
$user_data = array();
$user_data['first_name']=($this->Users->get_user($id)->name);
$user_data['url'] = site_url("users/password/" . $hash);
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Password Reset';
$view = 'forgot';
sendEmail($to, $subject, $user_data, $view);
```

There is no error in log as well.

Comment: Are warnings and notices on? Post your forgot password code as well.

Comment: I have updated the answer,and yes errors and warnings are On @NeilPatrao